# Error Correction Convolutional Codes - Coding Theory

Tags: coding-theory

This question is regarding convolutional encoders. I have come across an encoder that has a constraint length 7 and a generator polynomial of {133, 171}.

My questions are next.

1- Does this mean that the input to the encoder is a maximum length of 7 bit sequence? Lets assume for now that the D transform of the input sequence is denoted by u(D).

2- Given that the generation polynomial is {133, 171}, can I tell what $G_1(D)$ and $G_2(D)$ is?

3- Is the output of the encoder G(D)*u(D)

Looking forward for your opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a $(2,1)$ (nonsystematic) convolutional code meaning that there
is one input stream of bits $u(D)$ and two output streams of bits.
The output streams are often *interleaved* into a single bit stream with
twice as many bits per unit time as the input stream, but it is best
to keep them separate (and at the same bit rate as the input stream)
for conceptual reasons.

The input to the encoder can be arbitrarily long; the *constraint length*
of $7$ means that each of the two current output bits of the encoder is a linear combination of the current input bit and $6$ most recent
 past input bits. The output streams are $G_1(D)u(D)$ and $G_2(D)u(D)$ where $G_1(D)$ and $G_2(D)$ are specified in this case in *octal* notation: express each *digit* of $131$ and $171$ as a three-bit binary number,
e.g. $131 = 001\vert 011\vert 001$, to get the coefficients of the corresponding generator polynomial e.g. $G_1(D) = 1+D^2+D^3+D^6$ or
$G_1(D) = D^6+D^4+D^3+1$ depending on your book's preference for writing
polynomials.
**Edit in response to OP's query:** The connection is as follows
$$\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 &  & D^2 & D^3 & & & D^6
\end{matrix}$$
or
$$\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
D^6 &  & D^4 & D^3 & & & 1
\end{matrix}$$

The output bit streams are the result of the *convolution* of the input
bit stream with the vector of generator polynomial coefficients (hence
*convolutional* code). In particular, the coefficient $C_{1,N}$ of 
$D^N$ in $(1 + D^2 + D^3 + D^6)u(D) = C_1(D)$ is
$$C_{1,N} = u_N + u_{N-2} + u_{N-3} + u_{N-6},
~ N = 0, 1, \cdots, \deg(U(D)) + 6.\tag{1}$$
(The bits $u_{-1}, u_{-2}, \cdots, u_{-6}$ needed in $(1)$ for small
$N$ are assumed to be $0$).
Note that $C_1(D)$ is of degree $\deg(U(D)) + 6$ and thus
has $6$ more bits
than the input stream $u(D)$. In particular, in applying $(1)$
for $N = \deg(U(D)) + 1, \deg(U(D)) + 2,$ etc., $u_N, u_{N+1}, $ etc.
are taken to be $0$.

In engineering terms, there is a (first-in, first-out) buffer 
or linear shift register that stores the previous $6$ data bits
$u_{N-1}, u_{N-2}, \ldots. u_{N-6}$, and the
output bit is a linear combination (e.g. as in $(1)$) of
these $6$ bits and the *current* input bit $u_N$. After doing this computation, all the bits in the buffer shift right by one position
($u_{N-6}$ is lost off the right end; we don't need it any more)
and the current input bit $u_N$ enters the buffer. For the computation
of the *next* output bit $C_{1,N+1}$, the buffer now contains
$(u_N, u_{N-1}, \cdots, u_{N-5})$ and the current input bit is
$u_{N+1}$, exactly as described by $(1)$. Thus, the process of
computing the last six bits of each of the output streams can be 
thought of
as including pumping in six $0$'s to clear out that buffer.
Bear in mind that the *next* codeword transmission will be assuming that
the buffer contains $0$'s to start with (remember $u_{-6} = u_{-5}
= \cdots = u_{-1} = 0$??), and so the flushing of the buffer is a necessary housekeeping step. Since the corresponding 12 output
bits *do* have information about the last few data bits, they are
included in the previous codeword instead of being discarded.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation, do you mean to write $G_1(D)= 1+ D^3+D^4+D^6$ instead of  $G_1(D)= 1+ D^2+D^3+D^6$ .. Does the constraint length 7 show up from the fact that $G(D)$ is polynomial of order 6? I didn't understand the last part you wrote *This corresponds to 6 0 bits being used as the input to the encoder following the last data bit udegu(D). In engineering terms, there are 6 data bit sitting in a buffer when the input bit stream ends, and these are being flushed out of the buffer by the 6 extra 0's coming in.* Can you please explain to me more what you meant Thanks@Dilip Sarwate